# Linear mapping being not open and not closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $T : V → V$ be a linear mapping, where V is a subspace of the Hilbert space H with orthogonal basis $(e_k)_{k≥1}$,

$V = \operatorname{span}\{e_k : k ≥ 1\}.$

$T(e_1) = e_1$ and $T(e_k) = ke_1+e_k$, for all $n ≥ 2$.

I know that $T^{-1}$ is bounded and that $T$ bijective is.
I have problems to show that $T$ is not open and not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the set$$C=\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac{e_k}k\,\middle|\,k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\right\}.$$Since $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{e_k}k=0$, $C$ is a closed set. But $T(C)$ is not closed, because$$T(C)=\{0\}\cup\left\{e_1+\frac{e_k}k\,\middle|\,k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\right\},$$which is not closed, since$$\lim_{k\to\infty}e_1+\frac{e_k}k=e_1\notin T(C).$$Therefore, $T$ is not a closed map.

In order to prove that $T$ is not an open map, I will prove that $T^{-1}$ is unbounded (I don't know why you claim otherwise). Note that$$(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}):T(e_k-ke_1)=ke_1+e_k-ke_1=e_k.$$Therefore,$$(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}):T^{-1}(e_k)=e_k-ke_1$$and, since each $e_k$ has norm $1$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty}\|e_k-ke_1\|=+\infty$, $T^{-1}$ is unbounded. Therefore, $T$ cannot be an open map.

Answer (score 0):

Why follows it from $T^{-1} $ unbounded that $T$ can't be an open map?

From the Open Mapping Theorem we have that $T^{-1}$ unbounded $\Rightarrow$  $T^{-1}$ not a closed linear map.